# How to make a QString from a QTextStream?

Tags: qt, qstring

Will this work?

```
QString bozo;
QFile filevar("sometextfile.txt");

QTextStream in(&filevar);

while(!in.atEnd()) {
QString line = in.readLine();    
bozo = bozo +  line;  

}

filevar.close();
```

Will bozo be the entirety of sometextfile.txt?

Comment: You don't open the file, look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm building a BB10 app and unfortunately I can't get this to work. I'm most sure it is something else I am doing so. But I can't choose an answer until I figure what else is wrong.

Comment: Well, it should work, it is simple and straightforward. Debug your code step by step and you will find your mistake. BB doesn't change QFile, so the problem is your implementation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why even read line by line? You could optimize it a little more and reduce unnecessary re-allocations of the string as you add lines to it:

```
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;
QTextStream in(&file);
QString text;    
text = in.readAll();
file.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

As ddriver mentions, you should first open the file using `file.open(…);` Other than that, yes `bozo` will contain the entirety of the file using the code you have.

One thing to note in ddriver's code is that `text.reserve(file.size());` is unnecessary because on the following line:

```
text = in.readAll();
```

This will replace `text` with a new string so the call to `text.reserve(file.size());` would have just done unused work.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is pointless to resize considering the string considering there is no initial data to append to. gonna fix my answer as well...