# Reading entire file to QString

Tags: qt, file-io

I'm trying to read all the files in a folder, store them in `fileList` via `entryList()` and then, for each file in that folder, open it and read its contents into a `QString`. I think this should be easy, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The error I'm getting now says:

`no matching function for call to 'QTextStream::QTextStream(QFile*, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag)'`

I understand that this relates to the *wrong* way I'm declaring the `QTextStream`, but the thing is that examples I found seem to *DO* this, so, why can't I?

Also, I noticed that if I add the test to check if the file open was successful, I get a warning saying "access denied", even if I'm just reading. Although, I can read the contents of the folder and even populate a `QListWidget` with those files with no problem.

The fact that these are *.JSON files should not matter, right?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612103/qt-reading-from-a-text-file), [this](http://forrst.com/posts/Reading_a_file_into_a_string_with_QT-gW6) and [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_read_data_from_a_file_in_Qt) examples, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
foreach(QString fileName, fileList){

    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString s;

    QTextStream s1(&file, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    s.append(s1.readAll());

    qDebug() << "string content:" << s; // empty!!!

}
```

**UPDATE**
With the modification suggested by cmannett85, I no longer get the error, but for some reason the string `s` is still empty in the end.
Regarding the read/write permissions in the folder, I have now noticed that if I test

```
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0,"error",file.errorString());
        }
```

I get two warnings - I'm suspecting provoked by `.` and `..` - when I run the loop. Before it produced 32 warnings and I have 30 files inside the folder.
Anyway, the files I'm trying to read are *.JSON and according to the properties dialog in Windows 7, they aren't set either as *read-only* or *hidden*. I can write files in the exact same folder with the same program.

There is one thing that I wonder if could be the reason for this: the filename contains `.` before the extension, ie, `ID.file.16.json`.

**UPDATE 2**
It is not related to the filename having `.` Tested it with different files and the result is the same.

Also,the two warnings were indeed related to the `.` and `..`. `QDir::Filters` solved the problem. Curiously, though, should I apply the `QDir::Files` filter, everything is ok; but if I use the `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` filter, no files are detected whatsoever, contrary to the Qt Assistant explanation that says that only these two elements are ignored using this filter.

**UPDATE 3**

Followed ddriver's suggestion, but still isn't working. Current code, including the retrieval of of the files in the folder is:

```
QDir assetsFolder = QDir("C:/Users/THB7OI/Desktop/app/qt-book/chap08/items");

QStringList files = assetsFolder.entryList(QDir::Files);

    // for each file in the folder,
    foreach (QString file, files) {
        QFile f(file);
        if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) break;
        QTextStream in(&f);
        qDebug() << f.size() << in.readAll();

        f.close();

    }
```

Comment: Did you `#include <QTextStream>`?

Comment: "access denied" on an Open() is not a warning, it's an error. Folder read permissions are different from file read permissions. If your open is really failing then that'll stop you right there. File IO is not a place to ignore return values.

Comment: @darron but I used another program I created to _write_ the files I'm now trying to read in the exact same folder, is it still possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. Normal, no. What OS & folder location? There are some convoluted folder permissions that could allow you to create and write but not read. On certain network shares, for instance.

Comment: It is a local folder in the desktop. Windows 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824043/how-to-make-a-qstring-from-a-qtextstream/15824150#15824150

Comment: @ddriver thanks, but I think the problem is elsewhere. The string comes out empty in the end, and `file.size()` returns 0... any thoughts?

Comment: @Joum - see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As pointed out, there is no such constructor for `QTextStream`.

I quickly typed those few lines to verify it is indeed working properly:

```
foreach (QString file, files) {
    QFile f(file);
    if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) break;
    QTextStream in(&f);
    qDebug() << f.size() << in.readAll();
}
```

And I do get the expected output - the size and content of each file. Try that code to check if you mistyped anything.

At this point I am pretty sure the problem is in your `fileList` - you don't check if `QFile::open()` succeeds and continue. Ironically, if `open()` fails and your code continues, you will get exactly 0 for the file size, and exactly an empty string for the result of `readAll()`. So the problem lies with your file names. And next time check if `open()` succeeds - not doing so is a very bad practice.

Another possible candidate for your files failing to open is if they are open for writing by some other process. Reboot your system and run your code directly to make sure the file access is not locked.

If that doesn't help too, head over to the Qt project website to post the problem there, and if necessary - a bug report.

Comment: On qDebug I get a `0 "" ` for each file in the folder, so this didn't work as well. I did it immediately after I saw your answer after starting the computer. I find it really weird that it is a bug, this is a pretty standard operation that I'm sure other people have done with success...

Comment: @Joum the `0 ""` probably means that the code did not find the file. Make sure that file `file` exists. Example: create a file `/tmp/test.txt` with some text in it, then use `QFile f("/tmp/test.txt")` and it should work. If then you still get `0 ""` as a result, it means the file is empty, or something else makes it impossible to read the file. (I just had the same result as you, but it was caused by a typo in the filename :-) hope this helps!)

Comment: @Wim dude, this answer has been marked as correct 3 years ago... WTH?

Comment: @Joum sorry for raising the dead :-) I was looking for a solution on a similar problem, and bounced on the same issue as you mentioned in your comment. In case someone bumps into it in the future, I hope they can find a solution this way. But you are right, I should not have directed it to you personally, my apologies.

Comment: this works for me too, but if the file is too large, your memory will suffer

Answer (score 5):

None of the examples you provide are creating `QTextStream` the way you are.  `QTextStream::QTextStream(QFile*, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag)` does not exist, use `QTextStream s1(&file)`, you have already set the open mode in the `QFile`.

> Also, I noticed that if I add the test to check if the file open was
>   successful, I get a warning saying "access denied", even if I'm just
>   reading. Although, I can read the contents of the folder and even
>   populate a QListWidget with those files with no problem.

Just because you have access to the folder, does not mean you can read the file contents.  If you have read access and they are plain text files, you should be able to open them in a text editor.  Can you?

Comment: +1 - note that `QTextStream::QTextStream(File*, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag)` (using a plain old `File` pointer) **does** exist and might be the reason for the confusion

Comment: I no longer get the error with your suggested correction, but the `s` variable is still empty... any ideas? Not only can I open/edit/save them in a text editor, another section of my program _created_ the files I'm now trying to read...

Comment: @Joum You should use `QIODevice::Text` as well as `QIODevice::ReadOnly` when opening the `QFile`.  Also try calling `file.size()` to see if Qt thinks there's any data in it.

Comment: Good call - `file.size()` always returns 0. Do you think it might be related to what I posted as edit in the question? I tried to change the filename so it doesn't contain `.` and the problem is still there...

Comment: Changed the `QDir::Filter` to display only files and I no longer have the warnings at the beginning - so it really related to `.` and `..`. Still can't figure out why the `file.size()` returns 0, though... Changed the `QDir::Filter` to display only files and I no longer have the warnings at the beginning - so it really related to `.` and `..`. Still can't figure out why the `file.size()` returns 0, though... Also, if I use the filter `QDir::Readable` the same files pop up...

Comment: *When* are you calling `file.size()`?

Comment: Immediately before I pass it to the `QTextStream`.

Comment: @Joum Is there any chance that the file is already open elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think so, but now that you mention it, I think I ran the code a few times without `file.close()` in the loop. You think that could be it? I'll reboot and get back here after testing.

Answer (score 2):

From your example will not work, because you get the list of the files (filename) not the file with the path;

```
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.json";

QDir assetsFolder = QDir("C:/Users/THB7OI/Desktop/app/qt-book/chap08/items");
assetsFolder.setNameFilters(filters);
assetsFolder.setFilter(QDir::Files);

QFileInfoList files = assetsFolder.entryInfoList();
foreach (QFileInfo fi, files) {

    QFile file(fi.absoluteFilePath());

    if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) continue;

    QTextStream in(&f);

    qDebug() << "string content:" << in.readAll(); // will not be empty!!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well after a really big headache, I figured out that a really basic and simple error was causing this - *the application path*.

On the last piece of code I added in the question section, I added:

```
assetsFolder.setCurrent("C:/Users/THB7OI/Desktop/app/qt-book/chap08/items");
```

before the `foreach` loop and everything's working now.

Although this ended up as the definite answer, obtained by the contributions of the people that replied first, this wasn't the original question I had, and for that reason I +1'd the other two answers I got because they specifically replied to what I asked initially.

Also, as ddriver's answer specifically targeted the `fileList` problem and got me thinking about the application path, I marked it as the correct answer.